# How to Create a "heavenly wobble" in FLStudio?

Tags: fl-studio, effect, pop

If you listen to the one below (I deeply apologize for those who are not kpop fans, and may hate listening to this) I don't know if you can hear it but there are some soft, low wobbles that seem to come from a heavenly place (a very soft reverb maybe), I would like to know how to do it in FLStudio... :)

Comment: It sounds a lot like a pad instrument that would be made using the Sytrus synthesizer to me.

Comment: Thanks... any way to get from zero to there? :)

Comment: Definetly a pad instument - edited for the short stop vinyl fadeout

Comment: Can you provide the timing of the sound in the above video?

Comment: I'm still trying to find a wobble sound

Answer (score 1):

May be because of the notes, you might hear it's wobble. 
But actually it's more like gliding sub-bass. You can start with "3x Osc" default sound.

**1 -** To get a gliding sound, you need to turn on the "mono" function which is in the fourth tabs of 3x Osc.

[image: gliding]

**2 -** As it's a sub-bass, you have to draw the note in a very low octave. May be around C3 or C2.

**3 -** To make it sounds slowly come in, add a little attack to the sound.
(here, you can side-chain it too)

[image: attack]